# VueJS Chrome Page Unresponsive

Tags: google-chrome, vue.js

I've recently built a new version of my application in VueJS and it's incredible!

Now I'm live I've had a few users come back to me saying they are getting in Chrome "Page unresponsive".

I've logged into their accounts from my end everything seems fine so it's got to be a client side issue.

I've also tested the application on BrowserStack on different operating systems and it seems fine. Has anyone come up against this before?

[image: Page title removed]

Comment: Usually page unresponsive happens when code enters an infinty loop, or takes too long, try to get the specifications of your users pc (in regards to speed) and make sure to test how you application behaves if requested network resources take longer to load or time out when loading, also test from IPv6 supported networks, as times may slightly differ in those networks, in the case their network stack is broken

Comment: Do you know any way how to tackle this? I mean, how to find the infinite loop, where to find the JS where the execution takes too long? Are there any recommended tools? It is so hard to find the problem if I cannot reproduce the page unresponsive error.